# Lync Powershell enable group members

Tags: powershell, lync

I'm trying to automate enabling members of a group for Enterprise Voice, I have the following (pretty rough I know), which work if there's only a single member:

```html
$telephoneNumber = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "LyncEnterpriseVoice" | Get-ADUser -Properties telephoneNumber | Select-Object -ExpandProperty telephoneNumber
$ext = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "LyncEnterpriseVoice" | Get-ADUser -Properties otherTelephone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty othertelephone
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "LyncEnterpriseVoice" | foreach {Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName | foreach {Set-CSuser -identity $_.UserPrincipalname –EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $True –LineUri "tel:$telephoneNumber;ext=$ext"}}
```

I can't figure out how to do a foreach otherTelephone and telephoneNumber. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a definite answer, but should help you nonetheless:

- You are calling *Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "LyncEnterpriseVoice"* three times in a row. Don't do that - it's inefficient and can even lead to inconsistencies if you don't get the same result back each time. Just call it once and assign it to a variable, then use that variable each time. This will also make your code much more readable, if you give that variable a good name.
- Understand what you want to achieve exactly - what objects are you collecting, what properties do they have and what do you want to iterate over? I can barely get that from your code and it seems you don't have a solid understanding of it either. Once you understand that, the rest is easy.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure what you mean by "I get the results I want". I'm pretty sure your variables do not contain what you think they do. It's helpful to build a script line by line - examining for each step what objects you are dealing with. Otherwise you just make assumptions and you will inevitably be wrong often.

For example in line 1, you seem to get an array of telephone numbers and in line 2 an array of additional phone numbers ($telephoneNumber and $ext). But in line 3 you use these complete arrays, instead of a single element, to build that LineUri string for each user, which can't possibly be correct.

Also in line 3 you use AD user objects as input and then do a foreach and get get the AD user object again for each user - a clear sign that you are not aware of the objects you are dealing with.

So for example:

Get the users we want to manipulate, including the telephone numbers. Otherwise you are dealing with three separate arrays and don't know how to match up everything - it's just messy.

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity LyncEnterpriseVoice | Get-ADUser -Properties telephoneNumber, othertelephone
```

Let's see what we have:

```
$users
```

Ok, it's an array of objects with all the information we need, but just out of curiosity, what kind of objects are they exactly?

```
$users[0].GetType()
```

Not very surprisingly, they are ADUser objects. Let's set some properties:

```
$users | foreach { Set-SCUser -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName –EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true –LineUri "tel:$($_.telephoneNumber);ext=$($_.othertelephone)" }
```

Note the subexpressions `$(...)` in the string - these are necessary, because else the variable `$_` would be expanded and the rest would literally be `".telephoneNumber"`.

One additional thing: you write "**tel:**...;**ext=**..." which is inconsistent and seems weird - maybe a typo?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll naturally take into consideration your first point, I'll assign it to a variable.

As far as the second point, I get the results I want, but I don't know how to handle it when there are multiple results. I'm assuming a foreach must be used, but can't make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's not only much more elegant, but works exactly how I wanted.